# git-send-email Causes "Must issue a STARTTLS command first" Error

Tags: email, git, smtp, postfix

I am attempting to send a patch with git-send-email through my Postfix mail server.  Unfortunately, whenever I do, I just get this error spat back to me:

```
<recipient@example.com>: host domain.markzz.net[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] said: 530 5.7.0
Must issue a STARTTLS command first (in reply to MAIL FROM command)
```

As far as I know, I have properly set up TLS on the Postfix server and have no other issues except when using git.  A few days ago even, I used git-send-email to send a patch to the same address.

If anyone needs any more information, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The patch was too long and all that is needed it to break it into smaller patches.